# CSS Transition Left to Right working, RIght to Left not working

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

If you go to my site: http://warringah-plastics.com.au/wplastics
you can see as you hover over a menu item in the main navigation an indicator arrows shows up on top of it. Then when you move your mouse across the menu left to right the CSS transition is pretty smooth. But when you move from right to left the transition kind of snaps past the menu item and doesn't look nice. Currently I am applying this CSS to the nav li element:

transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s !important;

I have tried experimenting with the hover CSS but no luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please place the relevant code here.

Comment: You know that page is loaded with 1.4 MB of scripts, right? Took me 30 seconds to open it

Comment: on ie8 i get the same effect both ways, it shows up the first item of the submenu, then a slight pause, then the rest of them show up.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is supposed to be that way, but here everything in the page seems broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

I suggest using css only approach, there are many ways that this could be done.
at least for me look pretty fluid. JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/u85as/226/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/u85as/236

```
ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;

    width: 100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

li:nth-child(1):hover ~ #arrow{
    margin-left: 0;
}
li:nth-child(2):hover ~ #arrow{
    margin-left: 100px;
}
li:nth-child(3):hover ~ #arrow{
    margin-left: 200px;
}
li:nth-child(4):hover ~ #arrow{
    margin-left: 300px;
}
li:nth-child(5):hover ~ #arrow{
    margin-left: 400px;
}

li:hover ~ #arrow{
    opacity: 1;
}

#arrow{
    margin-left: -50px;
    border:0px solid red;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    opacity: 0;

    transition:All 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition:All 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:All 1s ease;
    -o-transition:All 1s ease;
}
#arrow:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:0;
    border:10px solid red;
    border-color:red  transparent transparent transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
    <li>Menu 5</li>

    <div id="arrow"></div>

</ul>
```

---

Notes

I can't see any transition.

[image]

But you have a seriously leaking somewhere, first the page took almost a minute to load everything. The requests bar (blue), just stop loadin in 44.5 seconds.

and until then, the page is triggering like a million events, seriously just look at the size of the scrollbar. and the huuuge yellow bar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback. I will certainly be checking out the scripts, I believe it is a Twitter script that is not connecting properly to the API. Anyways if you can't see the main menu it is probably because you are on a smaller screen (I am in the process of fixing this as I am applying different CSS to optimise for all screens). If you go onto a normal larger screen using Firefox or Chrome you should see the transition effects when hovering from left to right over the nav items working smoother and from right to left not working as elegantly. Thanks,

Comment: I'm using 1920x1080, anyway I edited my answer to a real answer.

Comment: Hey,Thanks so much for the example it's great! I am no expert, definitely more of a noob. It would be great if you could tell me how I could adapt my existing code to suit what you've done or point out where I have gone wrong in my code. I would kind of like to know specifically how to get that nice easing to go the other way...which part of the css is critical to make that happen? Thanks!!!

Comment: I do not have time now, but I make the exemple more evident of how it works here http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/u85as/236/ added some comments, if you still not understand how it works let me know.