# CSS3 transition left to right

Tags: html, css

http://fiddle.jshell.net/at8eybrn/

How to set transition to go from left to right, in link above...

```
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  transition: all .6s ease;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

li:first-child a{ border-left: 10px solid #3498db; }
li:nth-child(2) a{ border-left: 10px solid #FF7832; }
li:nth-child(3) a{ border-left: 10px solid #16C4A7; }
li:last-child a{ border-left: 10px solid #FF7D9D; }

li:first-child a:hover{ background: #3498db; }
li:nth-child(2) a:hover{ background: #FF7832; }
li:nth-child(3) a:hover{ background: #16C4A7; }
li:last-child a:hover{ background: #FF7D9D; }
```

Comment: Is this the effect you mean? If yes, let me know and I'll write up an answer for you... http://fiddle.jshell.net/zct92qbu/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451214/css-transition-left-to-right-working-right-to-left-not-working

Comment: Hey yes that's exactly what I meant...

Comment: @Beejamin, can you please post me here some explanation about code, why is before needed and all other code you added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. It uses generated content to provide the 'colour panel' that moves from left to right when the element is hovered.

The HTML I changed to include an extra `<span>` inside the `<a>`. This is to allow the z-index of the text to be set, so it appears over the colour panel. The HTML now looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>More</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The important CSS is:

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  transition: color .6s ease;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

li a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  transition: width .6s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

li:nth-child(1) a::before{ background: #3498db; }
li:nth-child(2) a::before{ background: #FF7832; }
li:nth-child(3) a::before{ background: #16C4A7; }
li:nth-child(4) a::before{ background: #FF7D9D; }

li a span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

What we're doing is using the `:before` content to draw a box, 10px wide, aligned top, left, and bottom to the containing `<a>`. This is positioned absolutely, so it doesn't affect the layout of the other elements, and we can transition it independently.

When the `<a>` is hovered, we set the width of the `:before` pseudo-element to 100% with this selector: `li a:hover:before`. The transition makes it a smooth left-to-right movement.

The `<span>` inside the `<a>` is positioned relatively, with a higher z-index, to make sure it appears on top of the color panel. There's a transition on the color, to make that a nicer change effect, too.

A couple of other style points - I switched your color selectors to use `nth-child(1)` and `nth-child(4)` just for consistency. That way, if you ever need a fifth one, you can just keep adding selectors.